# React | Promise Uncaught Type Error on Promise.then()

Tags: javascript, reactjs, async-await, es6-promise

I have the following method in React, which check if the username in the `params.data`, is present in the list of Users. If the user is present we render the normal details view. If not we display a 404 Page.

```
  validateUsername = (match, params) =>
    listUsers().then(({ data }) => {
      if (Array.isArray(data.username).contains(params.username)) {
        return true;
      }
      return false;
    });
```

The thing works. It works lie, charm, I get redirected in the correct render every time. But I get this error which I am trying to make go away, as I am planning to test that case scenario.

Here is the component:

```
import { getUser, listUsers } from '../../config/service';
// The above are the services I use to call specific endpoint,
// They return a promise themselves.

class UserDetailsScreen extends Component {
  static propTypes = {
    match: PropTypes.shape({
      isExact: PropTypes.bool,
      params: PropTypes.object,
      path: PropTypes.string,
      url: PropTypes.string
    }),
    label: PropTypes.string,
    actualValue: PropTypes.string,
    callBack: PropTypes.func
  };

  state = {
    user: {}
  };

  componentDidMount() {
    this.fetchUser();
  }

  getUserUsername = () => {
    const { match } = this.props;
    const { params } = match; // If I print this, it is fine.
    return params.username;
  };

  fetchUser = () => {
    getUser(this.getUserUsername()).then(username => {
      this.setState({
        user: username.data
      });
    });
  };

  validateUsername = (params) =>
    listUsers().then(({ data }) => {
      // Data are printed, just fine. I get
      // the list of users I have on my API.
      if (Array.isArray(data.username).contains(params.username)) {
      // The error is here in params.username. It is undefined.
        return true;
      }
      return false;
    });

  renderNoResourceComponent = () => {
    const { user } = this.state;
    return (
      <div className="center-block" data-test="no-resource-component">
        <NoResource
           ... More content for the no user with that name render
        </NoResource>
      </div>
    );
  };

  render() {
    const { user } = this.state;
    const { callBack, actualValue, label } = this.props;
    return (
      <div className="container-fluid">
        {user && this.validateUsername() ? (
          <Fragment>
            <div className="row">
              ...More content for the normal render here...
            </div>
          </Fragment>
        ) : (
            <div className="container-fluid">
              {this.renderNoResourceComponent()}
            </div>
          )}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default UserDetailsScreen;
```

Not sure what is wrong, maybe the data is not there when I make the call, and I need async-await or something. I need some help. Thank you!

Comment: It doesnt work. `Array.isArray` returns a boolean, booleans do not have a `.contains` method (nor does any other JS value)

Comment: Ok, so even if I remove it, it won't stop complaining. What is the actual solution? Did I do it completely wrong?

Comment: Well then there is another error ...

Comment: `user && this.validateUsername() ? … : …` doesn't work. `validateUsername` returns a promise which is always truthy.

Comment: Well, *what* type error does it report?

Comment: Well, I am returning a boolean at the end, based on the result of those promises.. The original error, says: `ypeError: Cannot read property 'username' of undefined at Object.then` .After doing what @jonas suggested, I get this `Cannot read property 'contains' of undefine at Object.then`

Comment: @Bergi I mean the thing works. Maybe by accident, nor sure. But I get the correct render each time...

Comment: I really doubt you ever get the `this.renderNoResourceComponent()` based on the validity. You are never waiting for the promise, and you are not handling any errors. (And apparently, `listUser` doesn't return an object with a `data` property)

Comment: And yet, `listUsers()` are getting data. I debugged it and I see it clear as day. Look, I could be wrong since I am inexperienced, but I mean, I don't understand why my method works. I understand what you are saying, but I don't understand what you are suggesting as a solution. Sorry for the bother, I just want to understand the situation in general and  my mistake here.

Answer (score 0):

1. As mentioned in the comments `Array.isArray()` returns as boolean and you cannot call array methods on boolean values, you need to check if `data.username` is an array then run methods on it separately.
2. I also think you should be using [includes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes) instead of `contains`
3. To handle errors that occur in `.then` you can chain `.catch` which accepts a function as an argument. The function you provide will receive the error as an argument for you to handle.

```
const examplePromise = new Promise(resolve => {
  const data = {
    username: ['a','b', 'c']
  }

  setTimeout(() => {
    resolve({data});
  }, 1000);
})


examplePromise.then(({data}) => {
  console.log(data.username.contains('a'))
}).catch(err => {
  // VM1025 pen.js:13 Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: data.username.contains is not a function
  console.log(err)
})

examplePromise.then(({data}) => {
  console.log('works', data.username.includes('a'))
}).catch(err => {
  console.log(err)
})
```

Comment: I have expanded my answer, if you're going to downvote please explain why as it will help me understand how my answer doesn't answer the question. Simply downvoting doesn't help anyone.

Comment: I didn't downvoted you by the way. Actually, I managed to make the errors go away, based on your answer and an expanded answer I found as well in a blog... I ended up using includes as you suggested in a slightly different manner though... Will update in a few hours it is getting pretty late here... Thanks for the effort...